# What is the regular expression in Python that match ASCII alphabets only?

Tags: python, regex

I use the regular expression which matches both alphabets and digits.

```
prog = re.compile(r'^\w+$')
```

How can I just match ASCII alphabets only?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You must replace `\w` by `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: This isn't unicode-compatible, btw

Comment: @Patashu: You are right, but i think that the question here is to have ascii without digits that are in \w. But it's a good notice! I was looking for some \p{L} or [:alpha:] in python when you post it.

Comment: It can also match Chinese